# Compound of uniform and gamma probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, gamma-distribution

I am trying to compute the distribution of a uniform distribution whose upper limit is drawn from a gamma distribution.

That is,

$X \sim \Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$
$Y \sim U(0,X)$

We know:

$$f_X(x)={\beta^\alpha \over \Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x}$$

and

$$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = 
\begin{cases}
 {1\over X} & 0 \le y \le X, \\
 0 & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$

but I get lost at the integral

$$f_Y(y) = \int_{x=0}^\infty f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) f_X(x)\,dx$$

I'm embarrassed to ask because I think the answer must be simple.  But it's been too long since I've done this.  I get:

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{x=0}^{x=\Gamma^{-1}(y)} 1\, dx = \Gamma^{-1}(y)$$

but I don't think that's right.  Please help! I'm a neuroscientist and I'm trying to understand a distribution I've measured.

Comment: $$f_Y(y)=E(X^{-1}\mathbf 1_{X>y})=\int_y^\infty x^{-1}f_X(x)dx=\ldots$$

Comment: I'd have written $Y\mid X\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0,X).$ I suppose one could argue that conditioning on $X$ is already clear from the fact that $X$ is seen in the distribution, but at some point one wants to write $Y\sim\cdots\cdots$ and have that represent the marginal distribution of $Y. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Write out the integrand:  $$f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) f_X(x) = \frac{1}{x} \frac{\beta^\alpha x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}, \quad 0 \le y \le x.$$  So the marginal density of $Y$ is $$f_Y(y) = \int_{x = y}^\infty \frac{\beta^\alpha x^{\alpha-2} e^{-\beta x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \, dx.$$  Note two things:  first, that the lower limit of the integral must be $x = y$, because if $x < y$, the conditional density of $Y \mid X$ is zero.  Second, we simplified the integrand by writing $x^{\alpha-1}/x = x^{\alpha-2}$.  Now we write $$f_Y(y) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha-1)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \beta \int_{x=y}^\infty \frac{\beta^{\alpha-1} x^{\alpha-2} e^{-\beta x}}{\Gamma(\alpha-1)} \, dx,$$ and recognize that $$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha-1)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} = \frac{1}{\alpha-1},$$ and the integrand is now a gamma density for shape parameter $\alpha^* = \alpha - 1$ and rate parameter $\beta^* = \beta$.  Thus, $$f_Y(y) = \frac{\beta}{\alpha-1} \Pr[X^* > y],$$ where $X^* \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha^*, \beta^*)$.

Comment: Thank you! So $f_Y(y)$ is $\beta\over{\alpha-1}$ multiplied by the cumulative distribution function of $\Gamma(\alpha-1,\beta)$.

Comment: It is actually the survival function:  $$\Pr[X^* > y] = 1 - \Pr[X^* \le y] = 1 - F_{X^*}(y).$$

Comment: Problems like this remind me of why I prefer to say the gamma DISTRIBUTION is $$ \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} (\beta x)^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x} \big(\beta\,dx\big) \text{ for } x\ge0 $$ instead of saying what the gamma DENSITY is, with that stray extra $\beta$ that then looks as if it lacks a companion $x. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @heropup needs adjustments when $0 < \alpha < 1$, as $\alpha^*$ then falls outside the domain for the Gamma's distribution shape parameter. Thankfully the recursive properties of both [the incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Properties), and [the gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Motivation) itself, allow us to circumvent this limitation. Using $\bar{\text{F}}_X(x)$ to denote a survival function :
$$\begin{align}f_Y(y) &= \frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}\bar{\text{F}}_{X^*}(y)\\
&= \frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha-1,\beta y)}{\Gamma(\alpha-1)}\frac{(\alpha-1)}{(\alpha-1)}\\
&= \frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}\frac{(\alpha-1)\Gamma(\alpha-1,\beta y)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\\
&= \frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}\frac{(\alpha-1)\Gamma(\alpha-1,\beta y)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}+\frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}\frac{(\beta y)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta y}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}\frac{(\beta y)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta y}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\\
&= \frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}\frac{(\alpha-1)\Gamma(\alpha-1,\beta y)+(\beta y)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta y}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}\frac{(\beta y)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta y}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\\
&= \frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha,\beta y)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}\frac{(\beta y)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta y}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\\
&= \frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}\bar{\text{F}}_{X}(y)-\frac{f_X(y)}{\alpha-1}\\
&= \frac{\beta\bar{\text{F}}_{X}(y)-f_X(y)}{\alpha-1}
\end{align}$$

Which is perfectly equivalent to @heropup's answer, and now extends to the full domain of $\alpha$.